# Problem with is_page & wp_redirect

Tags: wp-redirect, init

I use cookies to determine which menu I should use on my website.
This is working fine, but I want to force the correct one if someone views the URL directly instead of via the URL with a query string (which gets redirected).

In other words, the URL www.yourdomain.com/?region=UAE gets redirected to www.yourdomain.com/uae/ and I want to be able to show the same result when a new visitor (with no cookies) clicks on a direct link to: www.yourdomain.com/uae/

I can't use a hook for the init as I'm using the is_page() function.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'pstv_set_uae_cookie');
function pstv_set_uae_cookie() {
    // Set cookie if on UAE Home Page & redirect back
    if (is_page('uae') && $_COOKIE_['region'] !== "UAE") {
        $expire = time()+60*60*24*30;
        setcookie("region", "UAE", $expire, '/', '.domain.com');
        wp_redirect( 'http://domain.com/uae/' ); 
        }
}
```

I'm getting the following error in firefox:

> The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or
>   refusing to accept cookies.

I know the redirect needs to happen before anything is output, but I can't access is_page until the wp functions are initialised.

Can anyone suggest a work-around?
TIA

Comment: `$_COOKIE_['region']` should be `$_COOKIE['region']` is it a typo? After that: 1) `is_page` is available from `pre_get_posts` action; 2) after `wp_redirect()` always `die()` or `exit`. But, all that aside, `http://domain.com/uae/` is a page link? It seems so. So when you go to that url, already are in that page, why redirect again? Is possible this is the cause of your endless redirect?

Comment: Thanks - it was a typo! :( I'll try again. It is a page link, but it only redirects if the cookie is not set to UAE

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the redirect function from the setcookie function

For setcookie function use `add_action('wp', 'your_cookies_function_name',10,1)`
Note that it's recommended to use `wp` and not `init` because `is_page` will not work with `init`

And for the redirect function:

```
function your_redirect_function_name()
    {
        if(is_page('uae') && $_COOKIE_['region'] !== "UAE"){
            wp_redirect('http://domain.com/uae/');
            exit();
        }
    }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'your_redirect_function_name',9 );
```

For more information navigate to this page [How to setcookie if is_page('page') ? should I use add_action('init') or there is another action?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/113662/37854)

I had same problem and I fix it my self