# How to setcookie if is_page('page') ? should I use add_action('init') or there is another action?

Tags: pages, cookies, init

I want to setcookie if is_page('arabic') or is_page('english') then redirect to home_url()
only if the page name/slug `arabic` or `english`, I think that init action happen before the code determine the current page, how to do that

Also after fixing that problem , how can I be sure that setcookie will happen before the redirect so the cookie which Has just set will be shown (because cookie needs refresh)

Below is my code

```
function site_set_user_language() {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['site_language'])){
        setcookie('site_language', 'ar', time()+3600*24*365*3,'/','.site.com');
    }elseif(is_page('arabic') || is_page('english')){
        if($_COOKIE['site_language'] == 'en'){
            setcookie('site_language', 'ar', time()+3600*24*365*3,'/','.site.com');
            wp_redirect( home_url());
            exit();
        }elseif($_COOKIE['site_language'] == 'ar'){
            setcookie('site_language', 'en', time()+3600*24*365*3,'/','.site.com');
            wp_redirect( home_url());
            exit();
        }   
    }   
}
add_action( 'init', 'site_set_user_language',10,1);
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'site_lang_home_redirect' );
```

Comment: got it works : by using `wp` instead of `init`, I will send the full code to help anyone has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

`template_redirect` and `wp` (as the OP noted in comments) are good hooks to do this. But there's a problem of logic in the sample code. I think it should be like:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cookie_redirect_wpse_113662' );

function cookie_redirect_wpse_113662() {
    # No cookie set, let's do it
    if( !isset( $_COOKIE['site_language'] ) )
        set_cookie_wpse_113662( 'ar' );

    # One of our pages, check/change cookie and redirect
    if( is_page( array( 'arabic', 'english' ) ) ) 
    {
        # Page is Arabic and cookie was English, change cookie
        if( is_page( 'arabic' ) && $_COOKIE['site_language'] == 'en' )
            set_cookie_wpse_113662( 'ar' );

        # Page is English and cookie was Arabic, change cookie
        elseif( is_page( 'english' ) && $_COOKIE['site_language'] == 'ar' ) 
            set_cookie_wpse_113662( 'en' );

        # Redirect 
        do_redirect_wpse_113662();
    }
});
function set_cookie_wpse_113662( $lingo ) {
    setcookie( 'site_language', $lingo, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365 * 3, '/', '.example.com' );
}
function do_redirect_wpse_113662( $where = '' ) {
    $where = empty( $where ) ? home_url() : $where;
    wp_redirect( $where );
    exit();
}
```

There's another problem, it would be better to go back to the original page when we click on the links *Arabic* and *English*: `home_url()` should be `site_url($last_url)`. See [this post](http://kovshenin.com/2012/current-url-in-wordpress/), by Konstantin Kovshenin.

For this, at each page, the link for those pages should be `http://example.com/LANGUAGE/?original_url=$last_url`. But that's a topic for another Question<sup>**`*`**</sup>.

<sup>**`*`** I've played with the concept and did [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/6524329).</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed my problem and sent solution, but I will study your code to understand more ways may it help me in my future WP problems, thanks alot

Comment: I don't need any of add_action(`'init'`) or add_action(`'wp'`) to make `setcookie` works?

Comment: @usamasulaiman look at first line `add_action('template_redirect'`... you **can't** hook `init` because when this hook is fired the `is_page` function doesn't work. In this case brasofilo had choosen the `template_redirect` action, when conditional tags work, and it is also the best place to do redirect, because when it fires headers are not already sent.

Comment: @G.M. Exactly, I got that I can't use init with is_page, so I decided to use wp instead and it works, as I mentioned in the below answer

Comment: @G.M., yep, not sure if best practice, but it works with the hook `wp`. &usama-sulaiman, I've optimized the code a bit, but will edit the Answer once more.

Comment: @usamasulaiman, I'm using `template_redirect`, but `wp` works too. I've simplified the code, removed the anonymous function and added a sample plugin that manipulates the Nav Menu to redirect to the current page and not the `home_url()`.

Comment: @brasofilo, Yep I noted that you've added extra redirect option `current page`. It was a great idea. I may use it

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it, I sent my question after more than a week trying to solve that problem, and it works finally just after 20 minets of sending my question :) I needed to wait 8 hours because I was new to wordpress.stackexchange

So as I mentioned in the comment of my question, The solving ideas were to:

1- Use `wp` **instead of** `init` to make the is_page do its effect.

2- **separate the redirect code** from the cookie function

So the working code is:

```
function site_set_user_language() {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['site_language'])){
        setcookie('site_language', 'ar', time()+3600*24*365*3,'/','.site.com');
    }elseif(is_page('arabic') || is_page('english')){
        if($_COOKIE['site_language'] == 'en'){
            setcookie('site_language', 'ar', time()+3600*24*365*3,'/','.site.com');
        }elseif($_COOKIE['site_language'] == 'ar'){
            setcookie('site_language', 'en', time()+3600*24*365*3,'/','.site.com');
        }   
    }   
}
add_action( 'wp', 'site_set_user_language',10,1);
```

and the redirect function:

```
function site_lang_home_redirect()
{
    if(is_page('arabic') || is_page('english')){
        wp_redirect( home_url());
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'site_lang_home_redirect',9 );
```

Comment: `is_page` accepts an array. I think your `if($_COOKIE)` logic doesn't work.

Comment: @brasofilo I did it and it works with me exactly like the previous code, Just I can't show you the link of my site now because it is still in the development stage

also `is_page` accepting these parameters 
 $page
    (mixed) (optional) Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug
        Default: None 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page